# Sort by date span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say we have the following model.

```
create_table :meetings do |t|
  t.datetime :started_at
  t.datetime: ended_at
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::base
end
```

How would I order a meetings_result, so that the longest meeting is the first meeting in the collection and the shortest meeting the last.

Something like

```
Meeting.order(longest(started_at..ended_at))
```

Obviously that doesn't work.

How would I achieve this, preferably without using raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without using raw SQL.

Using Raw SQL:

```
Meeting.order('(ended_at - start_at) DESC')
```

(works with PostGreSQL)

Comment: Seems elegant enough. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I removed the accept, because it didn't seem to work. But that had to do with a default scope. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

No SQL? Two options come to mind. Create an array of hashes and sort it there, or add another column in the db and sort on that.

```
# How many records in the meetings table? This array of hashes could get huge.
meetings_array = []
Meeting.all.each do |meeting|
  meetings_array << {id: meeting.id, started_at: meeting.started_at, ended_at: meeting.ended_at , duration: meeting.ended_at - meeting.started_at }
end
meetings_array.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:duration] }
```

Or, create another column:

```
# Is it worth adding another column?
create_table :meetings do |t|
  t.datetime :started_at
  t.datetime :ended_at
  t.datetime :duration 
end
```

Update this column whenever you have both `started_at` and `ended_at`. Then you can:

```
Meeting.order("duration")
```

Comment: How would I store the duration in a datetime column?

Comment: This is way too much for a simple order: First solution: you are using Ruby to compute a duration, but SQL can easily do it for you ; Second soluion: this implies a lot of handling behing the scenes : object updates, possible nil values, and it is a data that is already stored by the 2 columns started_at & ended_at

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I agree with you completely :-) Just answered it according to the constraints. Note the comments I added.